# How do you print an integer value within an object in scala?

Tags: scala

```
object perMissing {
    def solution(A: Array[Int]): Int = {
        def findMissing(i: Int, L: List[Int]): Int = {
            if (L.isEmpty || L.head != i+1) {
                i+1   
                println(i+1)}
            else findMissing(i+1, L.tail)
        }
        if (A.length == 0) 1 
        else findMissing(0, A.toList.sorted)

    }
    solution(Array(2,3,1,5))
}
```

I'm new to the world of Scala. I come from Python and C world.

How do we print an integer value, eg. for debugging? For instance, if I want to see the value of `i` in every iteration.

I compile my code using `scalac` and run it using `scala`.

Comment: Do you mean `println(i)`? Similar to `printf`?

Comment: yes, i mean similar to printf...
made some changes.. that's how i run it and it doesn't help me

Comment: If you add a `println` in the beginning of `def solution` to print the array, i.e. `A.foreach(println)`, do you see the output in the console?

Comment: I still don't... I kept it as line 3 in the above solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the signature of your `findMissing` function, it should return an `Int`. However, if you look at the implementation of that function, only one of the code paths (namely the `else` part) returns an `Int` - the `if` part on the other hand does not return anything (besides `Unit`), since the call to `println` is the last line of that particular code block. To fix this issue, just return the increased value by putting it at the end of the block:

```
def findMissing(i: Int, l: List[Int]): Int = {
  val inc = i + 1
  if (l.isEmpty || l.head != inc) {
    println(inc)
    inc
  }
  else findMissing(inc, l.tail)
}
```

Since `findMissing` is tail recursive, you could additionally annotate it with [@tailrec](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) to ensure it will be compiled with tail call optimization.